# PHP script only display one row of data in android studio

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask how can I display many `row`s of data instead of only one `row`. The following code will only display one row of record instead of multiple records are available. I'm using `mysqli_prepare` statements here. Or the problem is on my android studio coding? My application is implemented with login function and coding as below.

```
<?php
$host="DB_HOST";
$user="DB_USER";
$password="DB_PASSWORD";
$db="DB_NAME";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$parentic=$_POST["ParentIC"];
$password=$_POST["Password"];

$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT Parents_Data.Name, Student_List.StudName, Student_List.StudIC, Student_List.Form,Student_List.Class,discipline_record.Date,discipline_record.RulesCode, discipline_record.TypesofMistakes,discipline_record.Punishment FROM discipline_record LEFT JOIN Student_List ON discipline_record.StudIC = Student_List.StudIC LEFT JOIN Parents_Data ON Student_List.ParentIC = Parents_Data.ParentIC WHERE Parents_Data.ParentIC = ? AND Parents_Data.Password = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($selectquery, "ss", $parentic, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery,$name,$studname,$studic,$form,$classs,$ddate,$code,$mistakes,$punishment);

$user = array();



while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery))
{
    $user[name]=$name;
    $user[studname]=$studname;
    $user[studic] = $studic;
    $user[form]=$form;
    $user[classs]=$classs;
    $user[ddate]=$ddate;
    $user[code]=$code;
    $user[mistakes]=$mistakes;
    $user[punishment]=$punishment;            


}

    echo json_encode($user);

    mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery);


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: use `foreach` loop and try again.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud can u guide me on more? because I'm new to this. thanks

Comment: move your echo json_encode inside the while loop

Comment: @RST thanks for the help but sadly it doesnt make any changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like that:

```
$userGroup = array();
$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery))
{
    $user[name]=$name;
    $user[studname]=$studname;
    $user[studic] = $studic;
    $user[form]=$form;
    $user[classs]=$classs;
    $user[ddate]=$ddate;
    $user[code]=$code;
    $user[mistakes]=$mistakes;
    $user[punishment]=$punishment;

array_push($userGroup,$user);            


}

echo json_encode($userGroup);
```

Comment: maybe encapsulate $user in another json_encode. If you begin with this, you might consider to use PDO instead of mysqli_connect(). What is the error? Does it have to do with string?

Comment: apparently this is for a login function. after applying your coding it couldnt log in instead.

Comment: It could not log because it is trying to echo and array instead of a string I believe. You can have a look at the function implode() that permits to change array to string.

Comment: hey bro are you willing to help me more on this?Can I pm u? because I'm a newbie TT

Comment: Sorry cannot do more for you right now. Dig around the hints you ve collected here, you re pretty close to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110116/discussion-between-adrian-loh-and-nyluje).

Comment: why you cant do more for me :(

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use 2-dimensional array

```
$users = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery))
{
    $users[] = array();
    $users[][name]=$name;
    $users[][studname]=$studname;
    $users[][studic] = $studic;
    $users[][form]=$form;
    $users[][classs]=$classs;
    $users[][ddate]=$ddate;
    $users[][code]=$code;
    $users[][mistakes]=$mistakes;
    $users[][punishment]=$punishment;         

}

foreach ( $users as $user )
   echo json_encode($user);
```

Comment: you probably missed that I changed `$user` to `$users` in the `while`-loop

Comment: my app is implemented with login function. after using ur coding, it cannot login to the apps now.. but it has no error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing correct query, but when fetching results using one flat array instead two dimension.

Also, try to avoid publishing your DB credentials in public :) It is quite dangerous.

So you should do something like that:

```
<?php
$host="YOUR_DB_HOST";
$user="YOUR_DB_USER";
$password="YOUR_DB_USER_PASSWORD";
$db="YOUR_DB_NAME";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$parentic=$_POST["ParentIC"];
$password=$_POST["Password"];

$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT Parents_Data.Name, Student_List.StudName, Student_List.StudIC, Student_List.Form,Student_List.Class,discipline_record.Date,discipline_record.RulesCode, discipline_record.TypesofMistakes,discipline_record.Punishment FROM discipline_record LEFT JOIN Student_List ON discipline_record.StudIC = Student_List.StudIC LEFT JOIN Parents_Data ON Student_List.ParentIC = Parents_Data.ParentIC WHERE Parents_Data.ParentIC = ? AND Parents_Data.Password = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($selectquery, "ss", $parentic, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery,$name,$studname,$studic,$form,$classs,$ddate,$code,$mistakes,$punishment);

$user = array();
$users = array();


while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery))
{
    $user[name]=$name;
    $user[studname]=$studname;
    $user[studic] = $studic;
    $user[form]=$form;
    $user[classs]=$classs;
    $user[ddate]=$ddate;
    $user[code]=$code;
    $user[mistakes]=$mistakes;
    $user[punishment]=$punishment;            

    $users[] = $user;

}


 mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery);
 mysqli_close($con);
 echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: firstly thanks for the help but it makes the application couldn't log in TT

Comment: @AdrianLoh do you mean your application can not log in into database?
i changed your credentials - it is bad idea to share them in public. So, you should change first four lined of script

Comment: nope. apparently this app is implemented with login function. after using ur coding, it cannot login to the application . @s_mart

Comment: @AdrianLoh it is a bit strange, because this should not touch any of login side. Can you please show which way are logging implemented?

Comment: hey bro can us talk in pm? hope u can help me more on this because this is my project if I fail it then its terrible for me  @s_mart

Comment: @AdrianLoh not sure there is pm at SO. but you still can add snippet of your login part to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110117/discussion-between-adrian-loh-and-s-mart).